# Playframework! Relation between two models

Tags: list, playframework, one-to-many, joincolumn

I have to program a web application. The user has to be able to create a Questionnaire that contains a List of Question (so to create Question also).

I've created Questionnaire.java and Question.java and I've lokked for every way to link a List with the Questionnaire such as :
   OneToMany/ManyToOne way, with a mapping, with or without a JoinColumn, with Embeddedable , EmbeddedId....

I know those are supposed to work, but 
Every Time I try to create a questionnaire it works and every time I try to add a question, it has a pointer or SQL query error.

I did not put my codes here, because I've tried so many ways it won't be helpful.. It is all mix up between the solutions I've tried to find out.

If someone knows a way that work and could breifly explain me the method It would be very nice because I've been kind of mixed up with all the possibilities to do it.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Play 1 or 2? If 2, are you using Ebean as ORM?

Comment: Hello, I'm using play 2.1 and Ebean !

Answer (score 0):

You can look how I use it on example of forum application [Comment.java](https://github.com/vooolll/forum-on-play/blob/master/app/models/Comment.java) is oneToMany [Post.java](https://github.com/vooolll/forum-on-play/blob/master/app/models/Post.java). You also can look at usage of it on controllers.

Example:

```
public static Result save(long id) {
     Form <Comment> filledForm = formComment.bindFromRequest();
     if (filledForm.hasErrors())
           return badRequest(create.render(Post.find.byId(id), filledForm));    

      Comment comment = filledForm.get(); // get data from form
      comment.post = Post.find.byId(id);  // set the model which is oneToMany to this model
      comment.author = User.loggedUser();  // set user also one user can write many comments
      comment.save();   
      return redirect(routes.Posts.list(Post.find.byId(id).topic.id));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try this. In fact I think the main problem I have is the way I get back my object Questionnaire. Because of the static way, it wouldn't be able to modify attributs of the object already instancied. 
Your method seems to work ! 
Thanks

Comment: @user2524693 play is stateless framework so you mustn't keep reference for modelss previously created, keep the id of it and then, just select it by id again. If you want to modify it, you can do so in controller then update in the database and forget about it. If I don't understand you explain your problem more detailed.

Comment: I've been digging a bit more, and it seems that I need to instanciate object dynamically so that I can modify them later.. Stop me if I'm wrong, but I don't have null pointers issues anymore.
@Slow Harry, I can't select a questionnaire by id, because I can't get access to the list of Question then  and modify it..
 I managed to instanciate dynamically my objects by createing instance of a class without using new operator. 
However I don't know how to display attributs of an object created and modified...